# Using cell array as blocks to build matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell array

```
matr =

4×1 cell array

    [2×2 double]
    [2×2 double]
    [2×2 double]
    [2×2 double]
```

I want its elements to build a block matrix such that

```
A = [matr{1} matr{2} ;
     matr{3} matr{4} ];
```

But I need this to be generic (i.e. for `n` number of blocks). I can't figure this out. Is it possible to do it without loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) function? 
Something like:

`A = cell2mat(reshape(matr,2,2)'`

Comment: Be careful of the ordering; you need a transpose/permute in there to reproduce the example.